# Capture MouseLeftButtonUp on cluster?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I'm working on an esri silverlight project, where I have a HUGE amount of points (100k +) I'm plotting these points on a graphics layer, where I have a MouseLeftButtonUp event assigned.

On the individual points, when zoomed in, it works beauitfully, but when clicking on the cluster icon, it does not fire the graphics layer's MouseLeftButtonUp event.

How do i capture this event on the cluster Icon?

Thanks!

Comment: 100k points is not huge in GIS terms (millions and billions are) - MouseLeftButtonUp event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I already have a clear concept of the MouseLeftButtonUp event. I am not sure of what is the right way to capture that event on a dynamically created cluster.